# Derby.log output file does not get populated correctly

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm trying to look at the query plan generated by my database, but derby.log is not getting populated with query info. It contains things like:

- os.name=Windows 8.1
- derby.system.home=null
- derby.database.classpath=''

I'm using the following to attempt to populate it:

```
CallableStatement queryPlan = conn.prepareCall
    ("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(?,?)");
queryPlan.setString(1,"derby.language.logQueryPlan");
queryPlan.setString(2,"true");
queryPlan.execute();
queryPlan.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Derby Reference manual says about `derby.language.logQueryPlan`:

> This property is static; if you change it while Derby is running, the
>   change does not take effect until you reboot.

So it is really intended that you set this it the `derby.properties` or the command line when you start Derby.

Comment: Thank you! I created a properties object and passed it into the initial connection.